# How do I get Pycharm to recognise a class type?

Tags: pycharm

When I run this code in IDLE:

```
type(number)
```

I get the following result:

```
<class 'int'>
```

When using PyCharm, it does not give any results at all when typing `type(number)`.

I expected the same output inside PyCharm, but I did not get anything at all.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove redundancies and added code formatting to make it clear which parts are code. It would help if you explain where in PyCharm you typed this code. Did you write that code in a script and run it? Or did you use the Python Console in PyCharm to run this code? Normally you'd get that kind of output if you use the iPython interactive shell to run the code. If it's in a script, you'd have to use something like `print(type(number))` to see it.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you so much. I typed the code inside the script.
Your solution was the correct. I am totally so new, a lot to learn yet:-)

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer since it solved your problem. If it helped, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that others know your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between the interactive console where you can write commands and immediately see their output and executing code from a `.py` file. In the Python shell, you don't need to wrap your code in `print()` to see the output, but if you want to do the same from a file you need to call `print()`, in your case like so:

```
print(type(number))
```

In PyCharm, if you want to use the interactive Python shell you can go to **View** > **Tool Windows** > **Python Console**.